# Style a SelectionInput (radio button) in Gmail App Script Addon

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a radio button in a Gmail Addon and I want to customize the color of the radio button. Here is how it currently looks:

[image]

As you can see, the color is a greenish teal (`#009688`) by default. I want it to be something else.

I can't see any info about how to style the Selection Input in these docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input

Here is my appscript code:

```js
const card = CardService.newCardBuilder();

const section = CardService.newCardSection();

// I would like to customize this input.
const toneRadioButton = CardService.newSelectionInput()
    .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON)
    .setTitle("Tweak the suggestion to be positive or negative.")
    .setFieldName("toneField")
    .setOnChangeAction(regenerateSuggestionAction)
    .addItem("Negative", false)
    .addItem("Neutral", true)
    .addItem("Positive", false)

section.addWidget(toneRadioButton)
card.addSection(section);
card.build()
```

Any ideas how I can change the color of the radio input?

Comment: Hi there @SamHenderson ! There isn't a direct way to update the radio button colour on Apps Script. Could you please clarify why you need that in the first place? It may be a better way to reach your goal.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron! I updated the screenshot to show the UI of the entire plugin. As you can see, the radio button is green. But the rest of the UI is purple. I would like a consistent color scheme.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question. Since there is no direct way of doing this on Apps Script, I advise you to open an [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) feature request asking for this trait.

Comment: Thanks @Jacques-GuzelHeron. I made an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236160477

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer in order to better document this question. Since this feature (setting radio buttons colours) isn't available on Apps Script yet, @SamHenderson filed a feature request on [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). You can visit it here: [`Style a SelectionInput (radio button) in Gmail App Script Addon`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236160477). Now Google engineers will evaluate this request and may implement it in the future. To make things faster, you can visit the request and click on `+1`. The more people click on that `+1`, the more visibility the request will have in the eyes of the engineers.